# Unrecognized selector sent to instance for my tap gesture

Tags: ios, swift, unrecognized-selector

I have the following code

```
lazy private var _containerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(
        target: self,
        action: Selector(("didtapContainerView:"))
    )
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    tapGesture.delegate = self
    return view
}()
```

and this is the method

```
@objc final func didtapContainerView(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    setDrawerState(state: .Closed, animated: true)
}
```

and I am getting this error

> Forsa.KYDrawerController didtapContainerView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't know how to make the correct selector for this method. (It would be `"didtapContainerViewWithGesture:"`, but clearly you don't know that.)

So don't try. Use `#selector` syntax and let the compiler form the selector for you!

Just say `#selector(didtapContainerView)`. Done.

Answer (score 0):

This is Swift , Correct the selector to this

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,action: #selector(didtapContainerView(_:)))
```

//

```
@objc func didtapContainerView(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    setDrawerState(state: .Closed, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: no it is objective c, the project has some objective c and some swift

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail No, the code in your question has absolutely nothing to do with Objective-C. It's Swift code.

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail what do you mean by that the gesture written in swift and the selector written in objective C ???